# Share data between sibling components using non-singleton service

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular, is there a way to share data between sibling components using a shared service, where that shared service is *not a singleton*?

The only way I can think of doing that is injecting a *singleton* service, and then using a hashmap in that singleton service to reference other class instances.

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './sibling.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.scss'],
})

export class Sibling1Component implements OnInit {

  displayMode: string = 'default';
  foo: Foo;


  constructor(private s: SharedSingletonService) {

    // I need to pass an id, but how
    this.foo = s.getInstanceOfFoo('some-uuid');

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

// the other sibling

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './sibling.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.scss'],
})

export class Sibling2Component implements OnInit {

  displayMode: string = 'default';
  foo: Foo;


  constructor(private s: SharedSingletonService) {

     // I need to pass an id, but how
     this.foo = s.getInstanceOfFoo('the-same-uuid-as-above');

  }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

}
```

// a helper class

```
export class Foo {

}
```

// the shared singleton service

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedSingletonService {

  foos : <{[key:string]:Foo}> = {}

  constructor(){

  }

  getInstanceOfFoo(id){
    if(this.foos[id]){
       return this.foos[id];
     }

    return this.foos[id] = new Foo();
  }

}
```

so the main question is - how can I use the same id in the sibling component instances, so that I can look up the same instance of foo in the shared service?

Comment: how about using a separate singleton service to share common id?

Comment: yes that's what I am doing here, SharedSingletonService is the singleton, which creates multiple instances of Foo

Comment: the problem is, I need to share the same id in both sibling components. that is, the id used to look up the shared Foo instance.

Comment: the only way around this problem, I think, is to create child components programmatically, instead of declaratively with HTML

Comment: that's what I am pointing to :) . create another service, use them in both component- which will be singleton, sharing the same id... sounds good?

Comment: right, but the components aren't singletons either, they is an array of sibling1components and an array of sibling2components..

Comment: what is your use case for this? Angular can have service shared across components, not always need to be singleton.

Comment: the problem is how to locate (get a reference to) the correct service instance

Comment: in my case, there are many Sibling component instances, not just 2, and they are created dynamically

Answer (score 1):

If your motive is just to share the id for the service...
Create another service,

```
import * as uuid from 'uuid';

@Injectable()
export class IdSharerService {

 id: string;

 constructor(){
     id = uuid.v4();
 }
}
```

Use it in both components

```
constructor(private idSvc IdSharerService, private sharedSvc: SharedSingletonService )
{       
   this.foo = s.getInstanceOfFoo(idSvc.id);
}
```

Hope this helps.
You can use this NPM package to generate uuid:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: yes, but the problem is this requires hardcoding the id - in my case, the id is dynamic because there are many instances of the child components

Comment: you can use this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript. Generating GUID in javascript

Comment: the NPM package I referenced is very good, can be used in the browser or in Node.js easily - https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: yep.. if that's comfortable to you, it's great.